# Proving that there's exactly one function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

While going through my old notes, I found an interesting math problem/claim:

- Let $X$, $Y$ and $I$ be nonempty sets.
- For every $i \in I$ there is a subset $X_i \subseteq X$ with $X = \bigcup_{i \in I}X_i$.
- For every $i \in I$ there's also a function $f_i : X_i \to Y$ defined.

Now my notes say that:

"If the functions satisfy $f_i(x) = f_j(x)$ for every $x \in X_i \cap X_j$ where $i, j \in I$ and $i \neq j$ and $X_i \cap X_j \neq \emptyset$ then there's only one function $f : X \to Y$ such that $f(x) = f_i(x)$ for every $x \in X_i$ and every $i \in I$."

Giving it some thought, I came to a conclusion that this just means that there's exactly one function $f : X \to Y$ that extends all possible functions $f_i, i \in I$

The claim doesn't seem trivial at all, how would one go about proving that there's only one such function?

Comment: suppose there were two.  What could you conclude?

Comment: This is a classical type of theorem usually called "gluing". You will also find it in topology with continuous functions, and many other areas. In this case, it is trivial, however. Remember that a function is uniquely defined by the values it takes on its domain, i.e. $f=g$ iff $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the fact that ,$f_{i}=f_{j}$ whenever the subsets overlap is necessary for the existence of the extension.For uniqueness, pick any two two exetensions f,g,let x in X be any element, the first condition means that there is some index $i$ such that $x\in X_{i}$ ,So $f(x)=f_{i}(x)=g(x)$,this proves that for every $x\in X;f(x)=g(x)$,we conclude that $f=g$,i.e there is only one function extending all the given functions.